# what is jQuery <div> selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

im new to jQuery and i come to a line i cant understand and i see lots using it,

anyone can explain this:

```
var div = jQuery("<div>", { "class": "someClass" });
```

Comment: i know the regular selectors, never met this <div> one with this another parameter... thanks

Comment: It creates a `div` element with the `someClass` class, it does not select an element in the DOM, it creates a new one.

Comment: This code generates a `div` tag with class of `someClass`.

Comment: To add to adeneos answer, you might then use div.appendTo('body'); to append <div class="someClass"></div> to <body>

Comment: So this use of the `$()` function is not a selector... could be considered a factory method I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a string is passed as the parameter to `$()`, jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has `<tag ... >` somewhere within the string).

If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.

Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these elements. You can perform any of the usual jQuery methods on this object.

As for the second argument to `$()`, as of jQuery 1.4 the `$()` selector can also accept a map consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the `.attr()` method.

Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: val, css, html, text, data, width, height, or offset.

The name "class" must be quoted in the map since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it is not the correct attribute name.

[jQuery selectors documentation!](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: Wow, thanks alot for the detailed and superb fast answer ! :)

Comment: [Well, actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html) it does not examine if "it has `<tag ... >` somewhere within the string" anymore. jQuery will now only determine HTML by looking whether the first character is a `<`. Read [the blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/22/jquery-1-8-beta-1-see-whats-coming-and-going/) (search for "A string will only be considered HTML if the first character is a less-than sign").

Comment: It does say : In jQuery 1.9 (the NEXT version following 1.8), we’re tightening down the “looks like HTML” rule for the `$()` method. A string will only be considered HTML if the first character is a less-than sign, otherwise it will be assumed to be a CSS selector. So I guess I'm right! At least until version 1.9 comes out.